# How should I encode LaTex formulas to use as targets for a model with Tensorflow ?

Tags: model, conv-neural-network

I am working on recognizing LaTex formulas from a given image, and I was wondering how I should represent the formulas in my model (convolutional neural network).

To train the model, I input images, each associated with a LaTex formula.

However, I'm supposed to be able to measure a loss/cost so how should I represent the formulas ?

I though about one hot encoding the formulas. For example, if we consider only 4 letters `a`,`b`,`c` and `d`, for the sequence `bd`, and for sequences of 4 maximum characters, I would have this matrix as target:

```
  bd 
a 0000
b 1000
c 0000
d 0100
```

Is this a good solution ? Which other solution should I consider ?

Comment: If you have a matrix as the target, how do you compute the error that you will backpropagate? Also, why not using what [What You Get Is What You See:
A Visual Markup Decompiler](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.04938v1.pdf) used?

Comment: Could I use the Frobenius norm and minimize it ? 
You're right, I should probably use their encoding but I don't understand it. `The target, y ∈ Y, consists of a
sequence of tokens y1, y2, · · · , yC where C is the length of
the output, and each y is a token in the markup language with
vocabulary Σ`
It's not clear to me reading this how I can encore the formulas

Comment: Also they add:
 `The
decoder implements a conditional language model over the
vocabulary Σ`.  What does that exactly mean ?

Comment: Does anyone know why this might be suggested to belong on [SO]?